# Displaying icon callout when no text in data field using QGIS

Tags: qgis, markers, callout

I am using QGIS.

On my maps, I have **SVG Parking** symbols. I need to **use callouts** to move them away. I have also a reference number beside many of these icons, but not all.

How best to set this up?

I tried this and it almost works...
In the layer styling **background tab**, I added my SVG symbol. Created a field column for my reference #s and it displays. The original location marker point I do not need to see, so I **disable the symbol layer**.

What I cannot solve is how to display the icon when there is no reference # in the field table, just NULL?

Since it needs to see text in that field to display the background parking symbol, how do I find a workaround?

Is there a trick or is my approach wrong?

---

To elaborate more on this issue, here are some screen caps. My Parking Icon with the reference number beside it as a callout. I like this no problems.

[image: Parking icon with reference number]

Here are my setting in the **Background tab**. I display the blue square P marker using the Background tab becouse I do not know how else to get the **callout feature** to work.

[image: background styling tab]

In the main Symbology window I turn off the layer that would show a marker at the original point. I do not what this to show as I will be scaling the maps and all those markers would colide on my rendered maps.

[image]

Lastly here is my Parking data table with my **PLot column** that I added. Note how fid **156** displays **P4** because there is the number **4** in the field. But row **293** does not display **P** becouse there is no number in the field. (And I do not want one associated with that marker.)

Yet I do what it to show up just as a **P marker** with no number beside it. How?

[image: data table]